# TTS inside broadcastreceiver call for incoming call/sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech

I am working on call name announcer apps. But my project doesn't speak when SMS is received. It receives it successfully, but can't speak it. I think there is a problem with call of TTS from `BroadcastReceiver`. Here is my code:

```
public class SMSAnnouncer extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] mensajes = null;
    String cadena = "";
    if (b != null) {
        Object[] objetos = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
        mensajes = new SmsMessage[objetos.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < mensajes.length; i++) {
            mensajes[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objetos[i]);
            cadena += "SMS de " + mensajes[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            cadena += "Compuesto por...";
            cadena += mensajes[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            cadena += "\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Speaker habla = new Speaker();
        habla.speak(cadena);
    }
}
}


public class Speaker extends Activity {

TextToSpeech ttp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ttp = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                Locale loc = new Locale("spa", "ESP");
                ttp.setSpeechRate(2);
                ttp.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                ttp.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
            }
        }
    });
}

void speak(String sms) {
    ttp.speak(sms, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
}
```

---

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.callandsmsblocker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.callandsmsblocker.CallAnnouncer" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.callandsmsblocker.SMSAnnouncer" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `BroadcastReceiver` document

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

Initialize of a `TTS` object is asynchronous. A `TTS` object is not initialized until `onInit()` is called. Calling `speak` methods before `onInit()` is not illegal but will produce no sound.

`onInit()` will be called after the last line of your `onReceived()` code, which is `habla.speak(cadena);` Thus your code will produce no sound.

You should start a `service` in `onReceived()` passing the text message as an `intent extra` and let the `service` instantiate a `TTS` object and speak the message in `onInit()`.